# is it posible to use RyuJIT with earlier frameworks than 4.6?

Tags: .net, ryujit

There is my question sorry if it's silly but 
is it posible to use  RyuJIT with earlier frameworks than 4.6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All .NET versions 4.0 through 4.6 have the same runtime version number, v4.0.30319.  They are not side-by-side, when you install a higher version then it overwrites the earlier version.

You therefore get RyuJIT if you have 4.6 installed for any project that targets .NET 4.0 and up.

Projects that target <= 3.5 and don't otherwise override the runtime version with a .config file get the legacy x64 jitter (runtime version v2.0.50727) with no option to use RyuJIT.

Comment: Correct. I added a checkpoint in our .NET 4.0 application to make reject the original RyuJIT (we were affected by one of its 3 memory corruption bugs).